# Docusign disable requireIdLookup request ignored

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am creating & sending an envelope made up of server side templates and providing details in one request. Sample payload below:

`{
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "template_name",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "templateId": "xxxx-xxx-xxxx",
          "sequence": 1
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 1,
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "xxxxxx@email.com",
                "name": "Xxxxxxxx",
                "roleName": "Role",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "requireIdLookup": "false",
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "",
                "tabs": {
                  "textTabs": [],
                  "radioGroupTabs": [],
                  "checkboxTabs": [],
                  "numberTabs": [],
                  "emailTabs": [],
                  "emailAddressTabs": [],
                  "dateSignedTabs": [],
                  "dateTabs": [],
                  "fullNameTabs": [],
                  "listTabs": [],
                  "signerAttachmentTabs": [],
                  "ssnTabs": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

On Docusign server-side, the template is configured for an ID Check - "ID Check $" - but I am overriding that configuration in my payload above - requireIdLookup is false and no idCheckConfigurationName is provided. This however is being ignored. Why? Is there a way to do this in one payload? I would like to avoid sending more than one requests to docusign for creating & sending envelopes.

I would like to retain, the "ID Check $" configuration on the template but override it, because for QA purposes, no one whats to mess around with their SSN credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have authentication set at Template level so envelope will not be able to override that setting. For QA purpose, where you don't want testers to use the real or their personal data then you can contact your DS Account Manager and they can change the `LexisNexis Ruleset` in the DocuSign backend so that you can test it with some test data, DocuSign calls it `Red Herring Test Users`. Once you are done with your testing then your DS AM can switch it back on to non-testing ruleset. Or the other way to create two diff templates one with KBA and another without, and using code send envelope either for KBA enabled templates or not, doing this way you do not have dependency on DocuSign to toggle the KBA ruleset.